# OCaml type of the plus operator

Tags: ocaml

Why is the type of a plus ( + ) considered to be `int -> int -> int` as opposed to `(int * int) -> int`? To me, the second makes sense because it "accepts" a 2-tuple (the addends) and returns a single `int` (their sum).

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make a language where `(+)` has the type `(int * int) -> int`.  In fact, SML works exactly this way.  It just affects the meaning of infix operators.  However OCaml conventions strongly favor the use of curried functions (of the type `a -> b -> c`) rather than uncurried ones.  One nice result is that you can partially apply them.  For example ((+) 7) is a meaningful expression of type `int -> int`.  I find this notation useful quite often.

Comment: Could you explain by ((+) 7) is of type int->int ? That's confusing me. How does it go from int to int?

Comment: The short answer is that it's a function that adds 7 to whatever you give it.  It's equivalent to `fun x -> x + 7`.  For a longer answer, I can edit my answer above if you like.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield: well, technically, it's equivalent to `fun x -> 7 + x`, but here it's the same thing

Comment: Good point, true.  Need to keep this in mind for `(-)` (non-commutative).

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a little unhelpful, but it's because the function takes two arguments.

When a function takes a tuple, it is in effect taking a single argument.

Because `(+)` is an inline function, taking a single argument would not be useful, as it would look like `+ (1,2)` as opposed to `1 + 2`.